# Catch exception from included middleware

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, middleware

I have a Sinatra app and I'm using the rack_csrf gem to protect my forms, this gem raise an exception if the CSRF token is invalid and I want to catch it for logging purposes. Is there a way to catch this exception or get the returned status code from the main Sinatra app?

My code is something like this:

```rb
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  use Rack::Csrf
end
```

This is what I'm trying to capture: https://github.com/baldowl/rack_csrf/blob/master/lib/rack/csrf.rb#L42

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to [write a middleware](https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2011/07/13/introduction-to-rack-middleware/) that will catch that exception from your app and do the logging. Something like the following:

```
def call(env)
  @app.call(env)
rescue InvalidCsrfToken => e
  #log error here, then return a status code
end
```